# Getting mod_rewrite to work on OSX Lion

Tags: macos, apache2, osx-lion, expressionengine

I'm trying to get mod_rewrite to work on OSX Lion.

By default, Lion loads the mod_rewrite module.

In my /etc/apache2/users/neil.conf I include the following:

```
<Directory "/Users/neil/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But whenever I visit a page locally, I get the message: The requested URL /some-page/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file in place?

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the page if you visit domain.com/index.php/some-page instead of domain.com/some-page?

If so, this could be an htaccess issue. Consider checking out [EE's documentation on using an htaccess file to remove index.php from the URLs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/general/remove_index.php.html)